# Rsync not working with one server while it does with others using strato hidrive

Tags: ssh, rsync, ssh-keygen

On a CentOS 6.4 running linux server, I am trying to rsync a folder with strato hidrive (http://www.strato-hosting.co.uk/online-storage-hidrive/advanced/).
The server is running rsync version 3.0.9.

What I have done to set up the rsync to the hidrive:

1. Generated a rsa key that needs to be uploaded to strato using the following command: `ssh-keygen -f /root/.ssh/id_rsa -t rsa -N ''`
2. Saved the id_rsa.pub file to my local machine so that I could upload it in the strato hidrive controlpanel, when I upload it, it does say that it recognizes that it is a rsa key.
3. I've done a test to see if it works using the following command: `/opt/rsync/bin/rsync -av -e 'ssh' --rsh="ssh -p22" /home/user/example/ mystratousername@rsync.hidrive.strato.com:/users/mystratousername/`

Normally it would just rsync, but now it asks for a password (while I didn't use a passphrase). I do have this working on 5 other machine's but I set that up like half a year ago.

Comment: No answer for your question, but the `-e` and `--rsh` options are the same, so you can remove one of them. Additionally, ssh and port 22 should be the default values, so you can remove both:
`/opt/rsync/bin/rsync -av /home/user/example/ mystratousername@rsync.hidrive.strato.com:/users/mystratousername/`

Comment: BTW, what happens when you specify the id_file with `-i` option?
`/opt/rsync/bin/rsync -av /home/user/example/ --rsh="ssh -p22 -i "/root/.ssh/id_rsa" mystratousername@rsync.hidrive.strato.com:/users/mystratousername/`

Comment: I did try that, it made no difference. I did solve my problem, it is probably a key length requirement on the strato hidrive. See my answer for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the id_rsa.pub key-length, apparently the default bit length of the key was different than the default 2048 (like on the other server), so when I regenerated the key using `-b 2048` it did work for me. Do note, this is probably only because of strato hidrive requirements.